# Using CRF suite C++ on images

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, svm, crf

I have been implementing Object Localization and Segmentation of images.
I need to classify different objects on an image and segment the image accordingly.

I implemented a research paper which is as follows:

- Make super pixels of the image(done using Slic algorithm)
- Classify each super pixel using some annotated images
- Also I am using the Support vector machine classifier to classify every super pixel.

Till here my code is working correct. But the next part is improvement of the segmentation using Conditional Random Field which is a     graphical model to segment the image. But I have no idea how should I implement this Conditional Random Field model. I need to make a graph between the super pixels which i have done.

There is a CRF suite in C++ of which the link is provided but I do not understand how to use it for images that is what will be my training data for CRF model and which functions should I call of the library(CRF).

Now I would like to Ask how should I go about implementing the Conditional Random Field  Suite in C++ on this graph of the Super pixel.
I went through this but I am unable to understand how should I go about it.

http://www.chokkan.org/software/crfsuite/

Comment: Sorry asked the question for the first time here :P

Comment: Still more yelling?!? That probably doesn't help, but is simply considered impolite :P ... Does your keyboard have CAPS-LOCK on by default or what?!?

Comment: OK, now to your questions content part, which is unclear. Just putting a link isn't enough. I'm not willing to go there!

Comment: Not enough information [**from here**](http://www.chokkan.org/software/crfsuite/manual.html#id490441)?!? Your question is most probably not suitable here! Did you consider to contact the author directly about any problems (I'm also no so well versed with japanese)?

Comment: ohk sir thnks...i hope someone else answers it but I am trying it myself now also

Comment: _'... but I am trying it myself now also'_ Good approach!! Probably better than asking here in the first place.